# is dev have to write all of test cases in one API?

Tags: unit-testing

i have trouble when my company tell me write 16K test cases in just one API, it take many time and i think i just write default cases, and rest of test cases give it to testing team.

Comment: From my limited experience with unit testing write a test for every case that you might thing help A LOT when you then need to refactor some code, and it0's even more helpful if you write your test before you start writing your code as it forces you to know exactly the expected behaviour of your code. So answering your question, yes, it has a lot of sense to write tests but they need to test different things.

Comment: What do you mean "in just one API"? What is an API in your case. 16k test cases might be a lot or not a lot, depending on what amount of code you're trying to cover. And whether or not you or someone else has to write those tests is really not a question that SO can answer: that's up to your boss/company to decide.

Comment: Thanks y'all comment, I learned a lesson